# Find combination of array elements that exceed maximum array element

Tags: algorithms, search-algorithms

Say I have an array of integers like so:
`[2,2,3,5,5,5,5,6,6,7,7,7,7,9,10]`

I'd like to find all combinations of these values that when summed exceed the maximum (in this case `10`) by the smallest amount (in this case a number that is closest to `11`).

The function for this array would output `[[9,2], [6,5], [7,2,2], ... etc]`. If for example there is no possible combination that would make `11` it would try `12` and so on.

EDIT

This is not from an online course. I'm working on a hotel booking website. I have multiple rooms in the hotel, and I need to find all possible combinations for large groups. Imagine the array contains the amount of rooms by their capacity (2 x 2 beds, 1 x 3 beds, 5 x 5 beds etc...) and then I need to find all possible combinations of hotel rooms for eg. a conference of 37 people.

Comment: Welcome to [cs.SE]! Your question looks like interesting. If it comes from an online course or contest or article, please add a URL _in the question_. If it comes from a book or a paper, a reference. Besides paying proper attribute to the original source, all that information motivates and helps more people answer your question faster and better. (In case if you figured out this problem by yourself, please tell us a bit of background.)

Comment: There is some ambiguity in the question. Instead of asking for clarification and back and forth, I will just wait to see if you can provide a url or reference.

Comment: Your problem is probably very hard. The version in which you wish to know whether the minimal sum is at most X is probably NP-hard.

Comment: If the problem is actually a real world problem, then the number of different rooms is probably quite small, so being NP complete doesn't mean you cannot find the solution.